# How to redirect to product details page in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I want to redirect page on product detail page without opening product image in lightbox when we click on product image. I just want to open product detail page when we click on product (featured product). but currently it open in lightbox.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please edit the question and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @AmalMurali i jus want to open product detail page when we click on product(featured product). but currently it open in lightshow.

Comment: You need to disable the image lightbox pop up and then put in a `location` command sending the user to the desired page. I can't give a code example without seeing your code or site